# Header and Footer missing in modal popup

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to have a modal popup in grid view. I used the followin code inside my index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use backend\models\Relations;


$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Members');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$this->registerJs("$(function() {
   $('#popupModal').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#modal').modal('show').find('.modal-content')
     .load($(this).attr('href'));
   });
});");?>

<?php
    yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
        'id' =>'modal',
        ]);
    yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
?>


<div class="members-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Members'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        // 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [

            ['header'=>'Popup',
            'value'=> function($data)
                    { 
                        return  Html::a(Yii::t('app', ' {modelClass}', [
                            'modelClass' => 'View',
                        ]), ['members/view','id'=>$data->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-success','id' => 'popupModal']

                        );      
                    },
            'format' => 'raw'
            ],


            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn','template'=>'{update}{delete}'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

this is my controller code

```
  public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->renderAjax('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

now modal is poping up but not in the desired way. I am missing Header and footer(No close button).[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use model like below and i use Modal in top. you can use it as you are using. my modal code is like this and it work perfectly.

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
'id' => 'modal',
    'size'=>'modal-lg',
    'class' => '',
    ]);
echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
?>
```

and load the needed content to div "modal content" and using footer and header option you can modify your modal according to your needs. for those option refer the below documentation.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-modal.html